# Anchors and tabindex

Tags: tabindex

I asked this question in a Wordpress forum with no response. So trying here in hope of an answer or suggestion.

I'm using the Wordpress Twenty Seventeen theme ([here](http://dev.lisatraina.com)) and the multi-panel homepage. My menu is a series of "custom links" which navigate to anchors in each of the homepage panel sections.

The navigation to the anchors is not consistent. Some land where they are supposed to, and others land after the intended location. When I inspect the page code, the only difference in the panel sections is where 'tabindex' gets set.

The ones that work show tabindex set at ‘panel-content’ level:

```
<div class="panel-content" id="noted" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="entry-content">
           <p><a name="noted"></a> </p>
           <h2>Noted</h2>
```

The ones that land incorrectly have tabindex set in the “a” anchor link.

```
<div class="panel-content" id="video">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="entry-content">
        <p><a name="video" tabindex="-1"></a></p>
        <h2>A Video is Worth a Thousand Words</h2>`
```

It seems random from panel section to panel section. I didn't do anything differently when creating the page. I have never dealt with tabindex before.

Any suggestion on how to correct this, so the anchors land where intended?

Thanks in advance, Mike

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. Turned out to be a Wordpress plugin issue.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tabindex-for-home-homepage-panels/#post-10781852